# Why can't I use an interaction collector in a slash command?

Tags: discord.js

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const {
  MessageEmbed,
  MessageActionRow,
  MessageSelectMenu,
} = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("setup")
    .setDescription("Setup the bot to your server!"),
  async execute(interaction) {
    let array = [];
    await interaction.guild.members.cache.forEach(async (user) => {
      if (user.user.bot === false || user.user.id === "925077132865052702")
        return;
      array.push({
        label: user.user.username,
        description: user.id,
        value: user.id,
        emoji: "<a:right:926857658500251668>",
      });
    });
    let row;
    if (array < 5) {
      row = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
        new MessageSelectMenu()
          .setCustomId("select")
          .setMinValues(1)
          .setMaxValues(parseInt(array.length))
          .setPlaceholder("Nothing selected.")
          .addOptions(array)
      );
    } else {
      row = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
        new MessageSelectMenu()
          .setCustomId("select")
          .setMinValues(1)
          .setMaxValues(5)
          .setPlaceholder("Nothing selected.")
          .addOptions(array)
      );
    }
    let welcome = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("UChecker | Setup")
      .setDescription(
        "Please select from the dropdown below all the bots you would like to be notified for."
      )
      .setColor("FUCHSIA");
    let message = await interaction.reply({
      embeds: [welcome],
      components: [row],
      ephemeral: true,
    });
    const filter = i => {
        return i.user.id === interaction.user.id;
    };
    await message.awaitMessageComponent({ filter, componentType: 'SELECT_MENU', time: 60000 })
        .then(async interaction => await interaction.editReply(`You selected ${interaction.values.join(', ')}!`))
        .catch(err => console.log(`No interactions were collected.`));
  },
};
```

Here is my code. As you can see at the bottom I am using awaitMessageComponent and it says an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createMessageComponentCollector')
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\UChecker\src\setup.js:55:31)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\UChecker\index.js:38:3)
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\UChecker\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:90
    if (this.deferred || this.replied) throw new Error('INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED');
                                             ^

Error [INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.
    at CommandInteraction.reply (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\UChecker\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:90:46)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\UChecker\index.js:41:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED'
}
```

I am confused as I thought you could edit a reply? Could someone please help me out because I am really confused. I have created a reply so then it can be edited by the interaction collector and it says it has already replied.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [CommandInteraction#fetchReply()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=fetchReply) to retrieve the reply message.

```js
await interaction.reply({
   embeds: [welcome],
   components: [row],
   ephemeral: true,
});

const message = await interaction.fetchReply();
```

Answer (score 1):

Interaction replies are not returned unless you specify `fetchReply: true` in the options

```js
let message = await interaction.reply({
    embeds: [welcome],
    components: [row],
    ephemeral: true,
    fetchReply: true
})
```